# Users status with human readable timing

Tags: php, datetime

I'm getting a status message using FQL and the Facebook Graph API.

I'm not sure about the time format returned by the API.

I receive it like this:

```
 [time] => 1319588970
```

I want to convert it to something like:

```
 27-02-2012
```

How do I convert that value to human readable time?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us: 1) what you are doing (the code that gets the status message), 2) what the results currently are (the status message / time that it is returning), and 3) what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: This really has nothing to do with facebook at all other than you are using the fql.  It is just a php date issue http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a UNIX timestamp set in GMT-0. To convert it, do something like this:

```
$time = YOUR_TIMESTAMP_VAR;
$date = date('d-m-Y', $time);
```

Comment: I tried this. I am getting 01-01-1970 as output

Comment: I did storing like this $time = $data['time']; But it should be $time = $data[0]['time'];

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Graph API, pass date_format= as a parameter. It should accept anything that works with PHP strfrtime. To get the format you asked for, use

```
graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?date_format=d-m-Y
```

Comment: I am using fql. how to add this condition?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure there's an equivalent. If you need to use FQL, then you'll need to convert the date in your own code, using the answer above.